# How to overcome 'fatal error: png.h' when installing the 'distill' package in Rstudio - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, r, rstudio

After successfully installing R and Rstudio on my computer. I installed the 'distill' package as follows in Rstudio:
`> install.packages("distill")`.

After several minutes it ended with the fatal error:

```
/bin/bash: libpng-config: command not found
read.c:3:10: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
3 | #include 
  |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have searched for how to overcome this error in Ubuntu and did not find a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this fatal error is to install the 'libpng' package as follows:

`sudo apt-get install -y libpng-dev`.

Then, restart Rstudio and try to install the 'distill' package again. That's it.